# NativeExpressAdView adSize SMART_BANNER

Tags: android, admob

I have AdMob block in app layout like

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>

...

<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="350x100"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-..."
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/refresh"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In main Activity there is also AdMob initializeaion code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-...");
NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
// adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
// adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-...");
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(...)
    .build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

If in layout XML I set `app:adSize="350x100"` the Ad block is shown.
But when I try to set `app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`, the Ad block is missed, and there is error message in log:

> Received error HTTP response code: 403

If I remove "app:adSize"and "app:adUnitId" from XML and set it programmatically in Activity, uncommenting lines in code above

```
...
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-...");
..
```

Ad block is shown whith error message inside:

> Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.

How can I set Ad size to `SMART_BANNER` value?

Answer (score 0):

app:adSize="SMART_BANNER" is used for banner ad, not for Native ads. You must provide the dimensions for the Native ads.

You may set the width of the Native ad view to `match_parent` so that it looks okay on any device.